# rtp packets are empty in sip AudioCall

Tags: android, sip, rtp, phone-call

I'm developping a softphone with the native library of Android (`android.net.sip` and `android.net.rtp`).

I am having a problem with RTP packets. The packets are sending but they are empty, then audio is not received.

Seems that SIP communication is being done correctly because INVITE, RINGING, TRYING, BYE... and others packets are being sending OK.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import es.app.packet.MainActivity;
import es.app.packet.R;
import es.app.packet.utils.Constants;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.rtp.AudioCodec;
import android.net.rtp.AudioGroup;
import android.net.rtp.RtpStream;
import android.net.rtp.AudioStream;
import android.net.sip.SipAudioCall;
import android.net.sip.SipException;
import android.net.sip.SipManager;
import android.net.sip.SipProfile;
import android.net.sip.SipRegistrationListener;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SipUtil {

SharedPreferences prefs;

MainActivity mActivity;

//Para SIP
public String sipAddress = null;
public SipManager manager = null;
public SipProfile me = null;
public SipAudioCall mCall = null;

Toast toast;

String username;
String domain;
int conPort;
String password;

static SipUtil mSip;

AudioStream audioStream;
AudioGroup audioGroup;
AudioManager audio;
RtpStream rtpStream;

public SipUtil (MainActivity activity)
{
    manager = null;
    me = null;
    mCall = null;
    this.mActivity = activity;
    prefs = mActivity.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARE_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    mSip=this;

}

public void initializeManager() {
    if(manager == null) {
      manager = SipManager.newInstance(mActivity);
    }

    initializeLocalProfile();
}

public void initializeLocalProfile() {
    if (manager == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (me != null) {
        closeLocalProfile();
    }

    username = prefs.getString("user", "");
    domain = prefs.getString("domain", "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"); 
    conPort = prefs.getInt("conPort", 5060);
    password = prefs.getString("pass", "");

    try {
        SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(username, domain);
        builder.setPassword(password);
        me = builder.build();

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction("app.INCOMING_CALL");
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mActivity, 0, i, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
        manager.open(me, pi, null);

        manager.setRegistrationListener(me.getUriString(), new SipRegistrationListener() {
                public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri) {
                    toast.setText(R.string.conectando);
                    toast.show();
                    Log.d("/SipUtil", "Conectando");
                }

                public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {
                    Log.d("/SipUtil", "Conectado!!");
                    toast.setText(R.string.conectado);
                    toast.show();
                }

                public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode,
                        String errorMessage) {
                    Log.d("/SipUtil", "Error Autenticacion: " + errorMessage);
                    toast.setText(R.string.error_autenticacion);
                    toast.show();
                }
            });
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        toast.setText(R.string.error_conexion_SIP);
        toast.show();
    } catch (SipException se) {
        toast.setText(R.string.error_conexion_SIP);
        toast.show();
    }
}

public void destroySipUtil()
{
    if (mCall != null) {
        mCall.close();
    }

    closeLocalProfile();
}

public void closeLocalProfile() {
    if (manager == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        if (me != null) {
            manager.close(me.getUriString());
        }
    } catch (Exception ee) {
        Log.d("/onDestroy", "Failed to close local profile.", ee);
    }
}

public void initiateCall(String destino) 
{
    this.sipAddress = "sip:"+destino+"@"+domain;
    llamar();
}

public void colgar() {
    try {
        mCall.endCall();
        if(audioGroup != null) 
            audioGroup.clear();
        Log.d("/SipUtil", "Llamada finalizada en colgar");
    } catch (SipException e) {
        Log.d("/SipUtil", "Llamada MAL finalizada en colgar");
    }

}

private void llamar()
{
    try 
    {
        SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) 
            {
                Log.d("/SipUtil", "onCallEstablished");
                mCall = call;

                try 
                {
                    byte ip[] = null;
                    try {
                        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface
                                .getNetworkInterfaces(); en
                                .hasMoreElements();) {
                            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
                            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf
                                    .getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr
                                    .hasMoreElements();) {
                                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr
                                        .nextElement();
                                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                                    ip = inetAddress.getAddress();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (SocketException ex) {
                        Log.i("SocketException ", ex.toString());
                    }

                    audio =  (AudioManager) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    audio.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);

                    audioGroup = new AudioGroup();
                    audioGroup.setMode(AudioGroup.MODE_NORMAL);

                    audioStream = new AudioStream(InetAddress.getByAddress(ip));
                    audioStream.setCodec(AudioCodec.GSM);
                    audioStream.setMode(RtpStream.MODE_NORMAL);

                    audioStream.associate(InetAddress.getByName(mCall.getPeerProfile().getSipDomain()), 
                            11234);

                    audioStream.join(audioGroup);

                    mCall.startAudio();
                    if (mCall.isMuted()) 
                    {
                        mCall.toggleMute();
                    }

                    Log.d("/SipUtil", "HABLANDO... "+mCall.getPeerProfile().getSipDomain());
                    Log.d("/SipUtil", "Codec");
                    } catch (SocketException e) {
                        toast.setText(R.string.error_codec);
                        Log.d("/SipUtil", "Error Codec");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        toast.setText(R.string.error_codec);
                        toast.show();
                        Log.d("/SipUtil", "Error Codec");
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
                    mCall = call;
                    Log.d("/SipUtil", "onCallEnded");
                    try {
                        mCall.endCall();
                        colgar();
                        Log.d("/SipUtil", "Llamada finalizada");
                    } catch (SipException e) {
                            Log.d("/SipUtil", "Llamada MAL finalizada");
                    }
                }

                public void onChanged (SipAudioCall call){
                    Log.d("/SipUtil", "onChanged");
                    mCall = call;
                }

          };

          String origen = "sip:"+username+":"+password+"@"+domain;
          mCall = manager.makeAudioCall(origen, sipAddress, listener, 0); 

         }
         catch (Exception e) {
             Log.i("/InitiateCall", "Error intentando cerrar manager.", e);
             if (me != null) {
                 try {
                     manager.close(me.getUriString());
                 } catch (Exception ee) {
                     Log.i("/InitiateCall",
                             "Error when trying to close manager.", ee);
                 }
             }
             if (mCall != null) {
                 mCall.close();
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this example  https://github.com/Mobicents/restcomm-android-sdk/tree/master/Examples/JAIN%20SIP

see how RTP connectivity is establised on btnCall click handler